# How lenient should reviewers/moderators be before deleting answers?

Tags: discussion, support

**This one is only for users high enough on the food chain to be able to see deleted posts!**

The title says it all and I'm asking specifically for the deleted answer on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568838/telegram-unity-app-opens-in-browser) post.

Most animals (humans included) learn from their mistakes.  IMHO, there is now nothing to be learned by this user as his post was deleted <strike>and he/she (probably) doesn't know/understand the reasons.</strike>

Most users coming to the StackExchange network, don't really know or appreciate what it's all about. (Hey, I thought StackExchange was part of the ExpertsExchange Network in the beginning and that's why I lurked around for *months* before finally subscribing and *gave this pesky website my OpenID* )

So?  What's the verdict?  Delete the pesky comments and undelete the post???

Oh, and feel free to call me names and insult me: I'm a dinosaur: I'm old so I have a very thick skin (as not to feel the daggers in my back), a very broad back (I can carry tons of work) and especially: I've got a *very small brain!* (`Don't   t h i n k   t o o   m u c h!`). And people like me are nearly extinct as well!  :D

Comment: What does bother me is 3 (!) people adding pro forma comments. You only need one. Adding more is just plain rude.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out there is a link below deleted answers that says "Why was my answer deleted" and links to http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers. It would be better if we could a) stop people from rudely posting more canned comments and b) improve the existing ones so they are actually helpful.

Comment: @Seth Well, I never had any of my answers deleted for me, so I wouldn't know, but that is helpful info!  ;-)  How about re-opening this one and give the guy a chance to improve himself? (he *was* improving...  And very probably took the pro forma comments as actual `t y p e d` answers...)

Comment: I can't undelete an answer in hopes the OP will make it better. Seems all he had was a bug report, that doesn't make much of an answer. I will, however, convert it to a comment.

Comment: I thought that it can be some feature at the level `share edit flag` alike `one-way-post-convert` to convert some negative estimated post to zero estimated comment ... this the way, @Seth! ))